# Пересоздал view postgress

Tags: postgresql

Пересоздал view в postgress, в проекте появились ошибки 
аля

```
SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7
ERROR: permission denied for relation table213 CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL
```

в навикате все запросы проходят, мб нужно перезапустить бд?

Comment: честно говоря с PL/pgSQL не работал, но думаю из за пересоздания у вас слетели права на вьюху у того пользователя из под которого вы к ней обращаетесь.  Попробуйте дать заново.

Comment: Да, при пересоздании view и других объектов права слетают. необходимо заново выдать права чем то вроде `grant select on view_name to user_name`